# is there a way to configure this user input view in ssms?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I know it's possible to edit a view in ssms:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view?view=sql-server-2017

But is it possible to configure a user input view in the following scenario?:

### DomainTable

- DomainId
- DomainName

### EntityTable

- EntityId
- EntityName

### ConfigurationTable

- DomainId
- EntityId

### ConfigurationView

- DomainName
- EntityName

Let's say that the DomainTable data looks like this:

```
1   My-Domain-1
2   My-Domain-2
```

Let's say that the EntityTable data looks like this:

```
1   My-Entity-1
2   My-Entity-2
```

So let's say that the ConfigurationView data looks like this:

```
My-Domain-1 My-Entity-1
```

I want to provide the ability to directly update the entity name in the view to My-Entity-2.  So the user could just choose to edit the view and update this text value in SSMS. If a valid value is entered then the underlying association would be updated. In a normal editable view in SSMS, I think that for this scenario, the only option would be to include the id in the view and allow the user to edit the id the view.  If a user edited the entity name in the view then this would simply update EntityName associated with EntityId in EntityTable.

Is there any type of easy way to achieve what I want to do in SSMS?  It seems like at a minimum there could potentially be an SSMS plugin that could be used to accomplish this?

Comment: i think you need an `instead of`trigger on that view

Comment: Actually for simplicity I could simply create a table and implement fk's on DomainName and EntityName, instead of the ID's.  this is a bit unconventional obviously but would achieve the goal in a simple way for a basic configuration table.  Has anyone here used this design pattern or is this approach raising red flags in your mind?  This would add complexity for base meta updates but if there is a small amount of data and updates are not expected then there seems to be more value in providing simple mapping updates

Comment: This can be done by using an `instead of trigger`on a view. This means that inside this trigger you need to update the underlying tables yourself, and thus have a change to determine which table needs  updating.But it does needs maintanance and might get complicated when lots of tables/columns are used in that view

Comment: SSMS does not have the intelligence to do this.  The database does the work.

Comment: You should include ConfigurationView data.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment instead of triggers are supported on [view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx).